# Getting console details (height, width, etc) of parent process

Tags: c++, python, console, subprocess

This question relates to console details (width, height, etc..) as interpreted by a sub-process.

I wrote a short C program which simply outputs the width property of the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` struct.
When called on it's own via a standard console window, the width prints out as `80`.  When called from python code via a subprocess.open() command (with the python program being called from the same standard console window), the width prints out as `-23251`.  So clearly this width is not being taken from the parent process' console window.

Is there any way for a child process to inherit or view the details of the parent process that created it?  The child process would be in C/C++, with the parent process being written in Python.

Comment: As a side note, I also seem to be having this same problem when executing the applications that use that CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO struct through a batch script.  It's appearing more and more like any subprocess (regardless of what the parent process is) does not seem to inherit the console settings of the parent.  So this seems to stretch beyond just python, however for now I'm looking to see if there is a python solution.
Basically, the C programs are trying to print to a width that is dependent on the console width - since this number is not valid, the apps are crashing.